# How do I show places like airports at higher zoom levels using Google Maps API?

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I've created a map using the Google Maps JavaScript API, and turned off everything except airports using JSON styling. Airports are appearing like I want, but only at a close zoom levels, around 9-12. Is it possible to have them appear at all zoom levels, or at least specify a higher zoom level where they appear?

The JSON styling options just look something like this:

```
    {
        "featureType": "transit.station.airport",
        "elementType": "labels.icon",
        "stylers": [
            {
                "visibility": "on"
            },
            {
                "color": "#303944"
            }
        ]
    },
```

So, I can simply turn airports on or off, but not "on" at specific zoom levels that are farther out.

I've experimented with this:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/cloud-customization/zoom-levels

which does allow me to *prevent* airports from appearing at specific zoom levels by setting visibility to "off" for that zoom level, but unfortunately at more zoomed out levels, even if I set visibility to "on", they fail to appear.

Is there some way to tell the API to show airports at all zoom levels?

Comment: I don't think there's any more modification you can do to the default markers, but what you can do is create a custom marker for every airport.

Comment: @Yril this map will cover the entire US, Australia, and parts of Europe, so I'm not sure manually tracking down the lng/lat of every airport in those countries is feasible.

Comment: There are sources. Import what you need in a local database and create your own markers. There is no other way.